# How can I update a widget on receiving a broadcast?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-broadcast

I'm working on a widget that displays information from a completely separate app. The separate app sends a broadcast when its data is changed, and I want to refresh/update my widget upon receiving this broadcast.

I can't seem to work out how to update a widget from within a BroadcastReceiver however. Is there a way to do this? Or another method to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the separate app has special action for its broadcast, you can add the intent filter to the manifest of your widget. Something like this:

```
<receiver android:name="ExampleAppWidgetProvider" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="SEPARATE_APP_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

And just process it in [onRecive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) method of you *AppWidgetProvider*.
HTH.